# How do you order objects in a priority_queue in C++?

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I couldn't find any information on how to order objects in a priority queue. I tried this:

```
class Person {
    ...
    public:
    bool operator<(const Person& p) {
        return age < p.age;
    }
}

int main() {
    priority_queue<Person*> people;
    people.push(new Person("YoungMan", 21));
    people.push(new Person("Grandma", 83));
    people.push(new Person("TimeTraveler", -5000));
    people.push(new Person("Infant", 1));

    while (!people.empty()) {
        cout << people.top()->name;
        delete people.top();
        people.pop();
    }
```

And it's supposed to give priority based on age (older people get higher priority, and thus leave the queue first), but it doesn't work. But I'm getting this output:

```
Infant
Grandma
TimeTraveler
YoungMan
```

And I have no idea what this is ordered by, but it's definitely not age.

Comment: You have a `priority_queue` of pointers, it's sorting using the value of the pointers not the age.  Use `priority_queue<Person>` and remove the `new`s when you push.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`priority_queue<Person*>` actually orders based on comparing the memory addresses of `Person` object using the comparator `std::less<Person*>`.

Declare a `priority_queue<Person>` instead to order based on the `operator<` you provided.

Or if you insist on using pointers (for some reason) then declare as:

```
auto age_comp = [](const std::unique_ptr<Person>& lhs, const std::unique_ptr<Person>& rhs) -> bool {
    return *lhs < *rhs;
};
std::priority_queue<std::unique_ptr<Person>, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Person>>,
    decltype(age_comp)> people(age_comp);
// note: must pass age_comp to std::priority_queue constructor here as
// lambda closure types have deleted default constructors
```

Note that this is using smart pointers not raw pointers, the former are much more commonly used in modern C++ - don't use raw pointers unless you have  a very good reason to.

Also, `operator<` of `Person` should be `const` specified as it shouldn't change the `Person` object it belongs to at any point - the comparator of `std::priority_queue` expects the `const` and will likely throw an error if the `operator<` does not have `const` specification. So, alter `operator<` to:

```
bool operator<(const Person& p) const {
    return age < p.age;
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Also, I got an error which implied that I need to add const after the operator overloading function (before the body part). Why is const necessary here?

Comment: Ah yes, `operator<` should have a `const` specification as it shouldn't change `this` - the comparator of `std::priority_queue` expects it to be `const` specified so its necessary (and correct) here.